# Cannot access a bridged NSArray from Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch

Why can't I use an Objective-C NSArray from Swift? According to the documentation: [Working with Cocoa Data Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-ID61) Swift should be bridging an `NSArray<Type*>*` to `[Type]`.

I have this object defined in Objective-C:

```
@interface Data : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) NSArray<NSNumber*>* arrayOfNumbers;
@end
```

This method defined in Objective-C:

```
@protocol DataReceiver
- (void)onDataReceived:(Data*)data;
@end
```

And this defined in Swift:

```
class MyDataReceiver : DataReceiver {
    func onDataReceived(data: Data!) {
        test(data.arrayOfNumbers[0]);
    }

    func test(num: Float) {
        NSLog("%f", num);
    }
}
```

And I'm getting the error: 'Type [NSNumber]! has no subscript members'. But this:

```
NSLog("%f", arrayOfNumbers[0]);
```

Compiles just fine....

What's happening here?

Comment: Does this work? `NSLog("%@", data.arrayOfNumbers[0])`

Comment: @kennytm Strange, it does compile with this approach, but doesn't work when I immediately try to pass it to a function like this: `func test(num: Float) { NSLog("%f", num); } test(data.arrayOfNumbers[0])` (Gives the same error)

Comment: Do you really need `Data` as optional?

Comment: @vadian Not at all, that's just what Swift generated.

Comment: Note that `NSLog("%f", arrayOfNumbers[0])` *compiles* because the (Swift) compiler does not check the types of the variable argument list. However, it will not produce the correct output  because an object *pointer* is interpreted as a floating point number.

Comment: @UnTraDe: You can't implicitly convert an NSNumber to a Float. An NSNumber can hold any kinds of number (Int, UInt, Int64, Float, Double, ...), and you need to extract it using `.floatValue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message does not make sense but it is caused by the fact that you are trying to pass `NSNumber` to a method accepting a `Float`. That means that the compiler is trying to find a subscript method that would return a `Float` but obviously it can't find it.

```
func test(num: NSNumber) {
    NSLog("%@", num);
}
```

Should fix the problem.
Objective-C to Swift bridging works as expected.

Comment: That makes sense, I guess the error message was a bit unclear to me. Thanks!